# Storing Object and Updating it in Sorted Tree Set

Tags: java, treeset, sortedset

I am using a Tree Set to store some Signals as objects in my Tree Set and also want to update an object If the same signal comes again. So far I tried something but the problem is I am not able to get the complete object when I try to print it and Secondly I don't know if there is any way to update an abject and save it back to the set...
Here is my code 
Signal Class (Signal.java)

```
public class Signal implements Comparable<Signal>{

   String source;
   String name;
   int occurance;

   public void setSource(String source){
       this.source = source;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void setOccurance(int occurance){
       this.occurance = occurance;
   }


   public String getSource(){
       return this.source;
   }

   public String getName(){
       return this.name;
   }

   public int getOccurnace(){
       return this.occurance;
   }

@Override
public int compareTo(Signal arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

My Main Class

```
  public class SortedSetTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Create the sorted set
      SortedSet<Signal> set = new TreeSet<Signal>();

      //Create a Signal object for each new signal
      Signal sig = new Signal();

      sig.setSource("Source");
      sig.setName("Signal Name");
      sig.setOccurance(1);

      // Add elements to the set
      set.add(sig);
      System.out.println(set);
```

**The above print show me as object...How Can I see the set as String?**

```
      // Iterating over the elements in the set
      Iterator<Signal> it = set.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()){
```

**Here I want to print each object**
               For example take the first object and print the object (Signal) Source, Name and occurance and so on till the end of the set reaches.
          }
       }
    }

Comment: The code for doing that is trivial. What have you tried? Also, are you sure you want to always return 0 from the compareTo() function? That means that all your Signal objects are the same for comparison purposes, which defeats the purpose of the Comparable interface.

Comment: I dont need to compare my Signal objects what I am interested in is to sort the signals in the set... and the sorting should be done on the number of occurances of a signal... the more a signal has occurance on the top it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you're looking for:

```
    while (it.hasNext()){
        Signal sig = (Signal)it.next();
        System.out.println(sig.getName());
        System.out.println(sig.getOccurance());
        // do the same with source or whatever property 
    }
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but if I try to get the Source or Occurance after Name it gives me an exception

Comment: @UmairIqbal Pay attention that your `set` contains only one item! about the exception, there's nothing much I can help with unless you add to the question the error and stacktrace.

Comment: When I use only one print statement it gives me the data but fo rthe next print statement it says
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at test.SortedSetTest.main(SortedSetTest.java:31)

Comment: @UmairIqbal like I wrote on the previous comment, in the code you posted there's only *one* item in the set.

Comment: I add the whole signal object in my set and each signal contains , source, name and occurance

Comment: Thanks it works now... Is it possible to update an object of set... for example in this particular example if a signal comes for the 2nd time I want the occurance to be incremented by 1 and the set the occurance value for that signal to 2

Comment: @UmairIqbal see my answer regarding updating objects in sets

Comment: @UmairIqbal if you want to count occurrences using a set will be a bad idea - every time you'll "insert" you'll have to iterate the set looking if a similar object was already inserted. For that, better use a HashMap - but that should be posted as a different question on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: No When I new signal comes I store the signal name in arraylist I dont itterate over my set , everytime a signal comes I check it in my signal names list if it is not in the list add the signal to list and also add the information related to signal in the set but if the signal already exists I just want to change its occurance e.g signal.setOccurance(new occurance value)

Comment: @UmairIqbal that's right! when you say: "I check it in my signal names list" - it means iterating over the list and searching for this signal. It takes O(n) time while if you'd use a HashMap it would take O(1)

Comment: So you mean it would be batter to store the signal names in HashMap rather than a list right ?

Comment: @UmairIqbal that's an option, yes, but I didn't mean the `name` specifically - you can store the whole object too...

Comment: Can I sort the entries in Hashmap by certain property of the object ?

Comment: @UmairIqbal HashMap is an unsorted data structure. If you'll use an ordered DS the "find" and "insert" time will be O(log n) which is, again, bigger than O(1)

Comment: Is it possible to sort the Hashmap some how?

Comment: @UmairIqbal yes, you can import the `KeySet` into a `Collection` and sort it using `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: Another way will be to use a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly printing the set.
You just haven't implemented the `Signal.toString()` method to represent a `Signal` object the way you want it.

About updating objects in a `TreeSet`: the object must not be modified in such a way that the output of `compareTo` is changed.  If it needs to be updated in this way, remove it (using `Set.remove(object)`, update it and add it back.

That said, your `compareTo()` method always returns 0.  It should return `arg0.occurence - occurence` if you want higher `occurence` values to come before lower ones.
This is because returning a value less than 0 means `this` comes before the argument.  0 means equal ordering and > 1 means `this` comes after the argument.

Also, if you implement `compareTo()` you define the natural ordering of the class.  It is strongly recommended to also override `equals()` and return `true` if and only if `compareTo()` returns 0.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html (search for 'consistent with equals').  With the above implementation of `compareTo()`, this would mean returning `true` only when they both have the same `occurence` value.  If you don't want to implement equals this way (it is probably not correct) then you should write a class that implements `Comparator<Signal>` and pass that to the `TreeSet` constructor.

Comment: What is the output?  Btw you should implement Signal.toString() if you want to see the Signal objects contents.

Comment: [test.Signal@1690726] out

Comment: @UmairIqbal that IS the Set as a string, only the contents of the set are shown as object reference, because you need to implement toString()

Comment: How can I sort my set on the basis of accurance of signals ... The more a signal comes in the start of the set it should be placed

Comment: I didn't get your point regarding compareTo(), please explain it

Comment: @UmairIqbal Do you mean the implementation (`arg0.occurence - occurence`) or the part about the relationship with equals() ?

Comment: @UmairIqbal it evaluates to < 0 if `this.occurence` is higher than `arg0.occurence`, which means `this` will come before `arg0` in the natural ordering.  E.g. if `arg0.occurrence == 3` and `this.occurence == 5` it will return -2 and the `TreeSet` will put this before arg0.

Comment: Can we continue it in chat if you have time ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37841/discussion-between-herman-and-umair-iqbal)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString` in your Signal object to obtain a string that is more user-friendly than the default implementation in the Object class.

Also note that because all your Signals are equal based on your implementation of `compareTo` (always return 0) you won't be able to add more than one Signal to your set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to override toString method,insteadof using mutator methods try to use a constructor which implements all your instance variables and the third thing is TreeSet uses a 
Red-Black tree structure,and guarantees that the elements will be ascending order,according to the natural order.So in compareTo() method you can compare one of your variables to get the solution.